# Can I nest block or element inside modifier in BEM CSS?

Tags: html, css, nested, bem

I'd like to write something like that:

```
.block__element--modifier .blok {
    /*styles*/
}
```

The thing is I don't know if above way is right in BEM methodology which I use. In practice I'm creating a navigation for website which is going to be opened by hamburger-button. When user click the button (and the navigation is closed and invisible) then menu is going to be show (and in main navigation block  will be added the other `navigation--opened` class). Something like the following:

```
<nav class="navigation navigation--opened">
    <ul class="navigation__list">
        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="hamburger">
        <img src="obrazek.png" alt="Button to open menu" class="hamburger__icon hamburger__icon--opened">
        <img src="obrazek.png" alt="Button to close menu" class="hamburger__icon hamburger__icon--closed">
    </button>
</nav>
```

When the `navigation--opened` class exists that means the menu has been opened. So now I want to style opened menu. To make it I'm writing the follow:

```
.navigation--opened .navigation__list {
    /*styles*/
}

.navigation--opened .navigation__item {
    /*styles*/
}

.navigation--opened .navigation__link {
    /*styles*/
}
```

I make it to style opened menu and its components.

Is `.block__element--modifier .blok {/*styles*/}` way proper in BEM? Thank you in advance for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to style block's child elements by modifier of the parent block. So

```
.navigation--opened .navigation__list {
    /*styles*/
}

.navigation--opened .navigation__item {
    /*styles*/
}

.navigation--opened .navigation__link {
    /*styles*/
}
```

is fine.

But it's better to avoid styling other blocks using nested selectors.

See https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#nested-selectors for more info.